# How to trigger an AHK's functionality

Tags: autohotkey, keystrokes

I'm new to AHK scripts and I would like to be able to press #n (windows key + n) and trigger a series of keyboard combinations (shift + end, alt + tab, ^T, ^V, enter, tab, enter) each time I press that.

This is as far as I've gotten but no matter how much I read online about it, I feel i need some extra help (samples out there are usually super complex).

(Edited final code that worked for me thanks to Robert Ilbrink, a slight modification of his proposal)

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Word ; #n will only trigger when working inside Word.
#n::  ; [Win]+n trigger key
    ClipBoard =  ; Clear ClipBoard
    Send, +{End} ; [Shift]+[End]
    Send, ^c  ; Store selected text in ClipBoard
    Sleep, 100 ; ClipWait seems unreliable
    WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Send, ^t ; In my Chrome setup I immediately get a Google search page.
    Send, ^v;
    Send, {Enter};
    Sleep, 1000 ;
    Send, {Tab}{Enter};
    ;SoundBeep, 500, 500
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Lolo, What is it that you want? Create a new tab in chrome? I am not sure why you send multiple LShift and RCtrl commands. You try to put focus on a new Chrome tab, but how can you be sure this new Chrome tab is there (you could run #n inside Notepad and nothing useful would happen).. So what are you after?

Comment: OK, I'll clarify: I'm constantly reviewing some word files. From time to time I need to copy a line (shift + end), alt tab (I will always have chrome next in order to word), open a new tab, paste the copied string, search in google, tab + enter to open first result. I have RSI and automating this process I do literally hundreds of times a day will help my condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lolo, I'll give it a try, but I am still puzzled.

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Word ; #n will only trigger when working inside Word.
#n::  ; [Win]+n trigger key
    ClipBoard =  ; Clear ClipBoard
    Send, +{End} ; [Shift]+[End]
    Send, ^c  ; Store selected text in ClipBoard
    Sleep, 100 ; ClipWait seems unreliable
    WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    Send, ^t ; In my Chrome setup I immediately get a Google search page.
    WinWaitActive, Google - Google Chrome ; Wait for Google search Page
    Send, %ClipBoard%{Enter}  ; Send ClipBoard Text to Google
    WinWaitActive, %ClipBoard%  ; Wait for window title with search string
    Send, {Tab}{Enter}
    SoundBeep, 500, 500
Return
#IfWinActive
```

Added the Tab+Enter combo. This does NOT work on my machine, since Tab jumps to the Black Google+ menu bar....

Comment: This does not trigger on a keypress.

Comment: I am still writing, not finished yet....

Comment: The key combo consists of pressing tab and then enter. Tab selects the first result, enter accesses it (all of this once the google search has been conducted).

Comment: Somehow it seems the keystroke only works after running the AHK, not afterwards. E.g. I run the AHK, press the keystroke and it only works once. After that I have to run the AHK again. Also, it focuses on the chrome address bar but it doesn't paste what was copied. Tried adding a "Send, ^v" but it doesn't work (if I manually press ^v the right clipboard is pasted -so it's not a problem about copying)

Comment: Is ahk still active in the system tray? Remember that [Win]+n ONLY triggers when inside Word!

Comment: Yes, AHK is still active in the systray (I'm pressing #n inside word)

Comment: But it no longer responds to [Win]+n when inside Word?

Comment: I am testing this on my machine, wrote everything from memory, not tested.

Comment: Exactly. Also sometimes it doesn't switch to chrome (alt+tab not being sent after the sleep or something?)

Comment: OK, Try again, had a #IfWinActive in there instead of WinWaitActive. With regard to [Alt]+[Tab], that is why I placed the alternative [Alt]+[Esc], which often seems to work better. O I could just Activate Chrome no matter what!

Comment: Edited question, with the code stated I manage to get to the results. One issues remains: being able to call #n more than once in the script in word.

Comment: @LoloJones, Made some changes and tested it on my system. Seems to work now!

Comment: The script was hanging, waiting for the result of the search. That should be resolved now.

Comment: Great, it worked!!!! The only change I had to make is substitute the three lines between the send ^t and the send tab enter for send ^v and send enter, the winwait and send clipboard didnt seem to work in my terminal :). Anyway, thanks a lot, you've made my day!

Comment: Great, hope you learned from the exercise to create scripts yourself in the future.

Comment: Most definitely. One final question is: how did you solve the issue with the script hanging?

Comment: Since I could not use the [Tab]+[Enter] at the end, I briefly replaced it with SoundBeep, 500, 500 and noticed that the system was waiting in-definitively, never beeping. So I changed the WinWaitActive to only look for the search string and not the rest of the windows title. As long as it was waiting, it could not execute the next command.